# Raspberry Pi 3 POWER REQUIREMENTS

Tags: pi-3, power

I have a "**Raspberry Pi 3 Model B UK**" and I have an adapter with 5V-3A.

Can I use this adapter for this device?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Why are you unsure?

Comment: @SteveRobillard In raspberry pi site, [Recommended POWER REQUIREMENTS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) is 2.5A.

Comment: I think if you read it suggests at least a 2.5 amp supply. Second the Pi will only draw as much current as it needs, the 2.5 Amp recommendation is based on somewhat of a worse case scenario (i.e., unpowered external drives, wifi dongles etc.).

Comment: Best to do a test yourself witha a multimeter to make sure the adaptor is putting out at least 4.8V - some aftermarket adaptors are notiously bad. But the 3A suggests you've made a good purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Question's comments, Adapter with **3A** in output made a good purchase and it's worked.

Comment: Amy recommendation?  That would be great.